# How to reuse same function in more than one vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-mixin

I have onClick handler in 6 vue components that is repeated, I extracted it in this mixin

```
//mixin.vue
export default {
  methods: {
  onLastMonth () {
    // get first day of the month.
    // get last day of the month
    // call axios GET method.
  }
}

//component.vue
import mixin1 from './components/mixin.vue'
export default {
  mixins: [mixin1],
  name: 'component1'
}
```

I want to reuse that mixin in other 6 vue components but the onClick event fired this error in the browser console:

**Property or method "onLastMonth" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.**

Comment: sounds like you need a vuex store.

Comment: could you provide the mixin code and the one of that components?

Comment: [mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics) should be an object, while default export of `*.vue` files is a component. Try renaming your `mixin.vue` into `mixin.js`.

Comment: I changed .vue to .js and it is working !!!